# $\Omega$ is a nowhere-vanishing $(n, 0)$ form satisfying $d\Omega=0$ on almost Hermitian manifold , can we obtain $J$ is integrable?

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $(M, \omega, J)$ be an almost Hermitian manifold of real dimension $2n$,  $\Omega$ is a nowhere-vanishing $(n, 0)$ form satisfying $d\Omega=0$, can we obtain $J$ is integrable?

Comment: The metric $\omega$ plays no role here. This is a question about almost complex manifolds. Is that intentional or is there a missing condition?

Comment: J is integrable iff differentials of (1,0) forms have no (0,2) component. So its seems to me that writting $\Omega$ (locally) as wedge of (1,0) forms you should get the integrability of J.

Comment: Holonomia is right; the result is easy.